# How to add entries to my pathlist in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart

Im trying to add a new set of values into my pathlist for example 3:{ "x" : 30, "y": 30 , "r":10, "color":1} to my pathlist and i am stuck here at pathlist.addentries( what to type here) . Thanks in advance for any help

```
    Map<int, Map<String, double>> pathList = {
    1: {"x": 10, "y": 10, "r": 10, "color": 0},
    2: {"x": 20, "y": 20, "r": 10, "color": 1},
 
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add new values like

```
pathList[3] = {"x": 11, "y": 10, "r": 11, "color": 11};
or as any index pathList[i] = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add one value like this

```
pathList[3]={ "x" : 30, "y": 30 , "r":10, "color":1};
```

If you want to add multiple values you can use this

```
  pathList.addAll({
    4: {"x": 10, "y": 10, "r": 10, "color": 0},
    5: {"x": 20, "y": 20, "r": 10, "color": 1},
  });
```